# Dispatchgroup doesn't seem to hold other events, what could be happening?

Tags: swift, function, firebase, return, dispatch

So I was building this function `getQuestionValues()` to fetch and return an array of informations fetched on firebase. And it works until a certain point.
The function is correctly fetching the data from firebase and storing it to an array. I know that because when I print the array just after appending the last item it returns the expected result.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let nav = self.navigationController {
        nav.isToolbarHidden = false
    }
    nextPath = sortNextQuestion()
    getQuestionValues(statementPath: nextPath[0], alternativeAPath: nextPath[1], alternativeBPath: nextPath[2], alternativeCPath: nextPath[3], alternativeDPath: nextPath[4], correctPath: nextPath[5])


    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main){
        print("nextquestion is gonna be:")
        print(self.nextQuestion)

    }
}
```

Function I have built:

```
 func getQuestionValues(statementPath: String, alternativeAPath: String, alternativeBPath: String, alternativeCPath: String, alternativeDPath: String, correctPath: String){
    print("entering dispatch group")
    self.dispatchGroup.enter()

    let refStatement = Database.database().reference(withPath: statementPath)
    let refOptionA = Database.database().reference(withPath: alternativeAPath)
    let refOptionB = Database.database().reference(withPath: alternativeBPath)
    let refOptionC = Database.database().reference(withPath: alternativeCPath)
    let refOptionD = Database.database().reference(withPath: alternativeDPath)
    let refCorrect = Database.database().reference(withPath: correctPath)

    refStatement.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
        let statement = snapshot.value as? String
        self.questionFetched.append(statement!)


    }
        //fetching alternativeA
        refOptionA.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            let optionA = snapshot.value as? String
            self.questionFetched.append(optionA!)


        }

        //fetching alternativeB
        refOptionB.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            let optionB = snapshot.value as? String
            self.questionFetched.append(optionB!)

        }

        //fetching alternativeC
        refOptionC.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            let optionC = snapshot.value as? String
            self.questionFetched.append(optionC!)


        }

        //fetching alternativeD
        refOptionD.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            let optionD = snapshot.value as? String
            self.questionFetched.append(optionD!)


        }

        //fetching correctAnswer
        refCorrect.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            let correct = snapshot.value as? Int
            let correctString = String(correct!)
            self.questionFetched.append(correctString)
            //left this print here just to understand that the function actually works, it is just delayed
            print(self.questionFetched)
        }



        print("new question fetched inside function:")
        print(self.questionFetched)

    print("leaving dispatch")
    self.dispatchGroup.leave()




}
```

However, I'm not getting the result I wanted on the expected time. I would like to use its result on `viewDidLoad()` but it seems that the chunk of code inside `dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main)` is not waiting for the function `getQuestionValues()` to load, as I intended to.

What could be happening?

Comment: All of your observation closures are asynchronous. The calls to `refCorrect.observe(.value)` return near instantly, you leave your dispatch group, and you never wait for the observers to be called. Instead, you should be entering your dispatch group before the invocation of every observer, and leaving the group within the observer.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I have just made the changes you suggested: set the self.dispatch.enter() just before the invocation of every observer and the self.dispatch.leave() still within the observer like you said.

But the nextquestion array called on `viewDidLoad` is still empty.

Comment: Well you're going to have to provide a lot more detail if you want us to be able to help you. Have you stepped through the code in the debugger? Any observations?

Comment: I have just debugged  the code with the changes you suggested and the main thing is that it looks like the dispatchGroup.notify() still isn't waiting for the function to end. 

Here is the example of one of the observers I adjusted


`self.dispatchGroup.enter()`

        `refStatement.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in`

            `self.dispatchGroup.leave()`

            `print(snapshot)`

            `let statement = snapshot.value as? String`

            `self.questionFetched.append(statement!)}`

Comment: You leave your dispatchgroup before you're actually done your work (appending to your array). More troubling is that you have a race condition on `self.questionFetched`.

Comment: Why are each of your questions in a different database?

Comment: I have "nested" the observers together to leave dispatchgroup only after the array is filled and it got a little better, now the function is prints the full array. I have looked around on the internet over the concept of race condition (an element that tries to make two or more operations at the same time) but I was not able to identify it on my code yet...

Comment: They are not, they are on the same database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187748/discussion-between-alexander-and-guilherme-atihe-de-oliveira).